# ¿Cómo puedo exportar un data table a un archivo excel en c#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, excel, datatable

```
public void cargar_Nota(string fecha, string producto, string topologia, string causalidad)
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("with causalidad as (SELECT distinct replace(LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,Fecha_Creación, 120), 8),'-','') as fecha,[Producto/Canal],Tipología, Causalidad FROM [DMIN_AUDITORIA].[reclamos].[DATOSUNION2014]) select fecha, Causalidad from causalidad where fecha in (" + fecha + ") and [Producto/Canal] in (" + producto + ") and Tipología in (" + tipologia + ") and Causalidad in (" + causalidad + ") order by fecha desc", con);//Consulta trayendo los valores de productos con filtro de fecha
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        SQL.DataTable dt = new SQL.DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        con.Close(); }
```

Quiero exportar 'dt' a un archivo excel, la consulta 'sql' está bien, pues los campos variables ya los he enviado a cargar nota, pero no he podido exportarlo a un excel.

Answer (score 0):

Para el que le sirva, lo logre resolver

```
con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("with causalidad as (SELECT distinct replace(LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,Fecha_Creación, 120), 8),'-','') as fecha,[Producto/Canal],Tipología, Causalidad FROM [DMIN_AUDITORIA].[reclamos].[DATOSUNION2014]) select fecha, Causalidad from causalidad where fecha in (" + fecha + ") and [Producto/Canal] in (" + producto + ") and Tipología in (" + tipologia + ") and Causalidad in (" + causalidad + ") order by fecha desc", con);//Consulta trayendo los valores de productos con filtro de fecha
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("fecha", fecha);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);


        var excelApplication = new Excel.Application();
        var excelWorkBook = excelApplication.Application.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
        DataColumnCollection dataColumnCollection = dt.Columns;
        for (int i = 1; i <= dt.Rows.Count + 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= dt.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                if (i == 1)
                    excelApplication.Cells[i, j] = dataColumnCollection[j - 1].ToString();
                else
                    excelApplication.Cells[i, j] = dt.Rows[i - 2][j - 1].ToString();
            }
        }
        excelApplication.ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs("C:\\Users\\sburitic\\test.xlsx");
        excelApplication.ActiveWorkbook.Saved = true;
        excelApplication.Quit();

        MessageBox.Show("hola");

        con.Close();
```